# WCF:How to Copy value of request into response in WCF

Tags: wcf

When i m sending request i am putting some value in that and at the time of response it should contain that value how could we achieve this in WCF ?Could anybody explain with example?Another scenario is if my client sending request to service that service may call another service and so on so at the time of response how to copy that request information inside response?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataContract classes in the request and response, then simply read the value in from the request and add it to the response.

Comment: thanks for response but what if one service is calling another service and so on and at the time of response how i get same data in last response to the client how to achieve this ?can you suggest which approach is useful .BeforeCall(),AfterCall method is useful in this scenario?please explain me with example